# Drilldown com dois tipos de gráficos usando Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

Tenho um gráfico com drilldown e gostaria que o gráfico do drilldown mostrasse dados usando colunas e linhas, no mesmo gráfico, tem como ??

Tudo o que tentei até agora não deu certo e só acho exemplos de graficos de um tipo indo para gráficos de outro tipo (fácil!), porem, preciso de um drilldown mostrando dados em linha e coluna.

Obrigado.